# th using col width even though its outside col

Tags: html, css, reactjs, styled-components, col

I have this table and for some reason the `th` takes the col width instead of only the tds taking its width. Is there someway to like exclude the th from using the col?

here is the css using styled components

```
const TableHead = styled.th`
font-size: 4vh;
text-align: left;
width: 100%;

@media only screen and (min-device-width : 320px) and (max-device-width : 480px) {
    font-size 2.5vh;
    border-radius: 5px;
    padding: 0;
    width: 100%;
    background-color: black;
}

@media only screen and (min-device-width : 768px) and (max-device-width : 1024px) {
    font-size 2.5vh;
}
`;

const TableData = styled.td`
font-size: 3vh;
border: 1px solid LightGrey;
height: 100%;
text-align: center;
vertical-align: middle;

@media only screen and (min-device-width : 320px) and (max-device-width : 480px) 
, only screen and (min-device-width : 768px) and (max-device-width : 1024px) {
    font-size 2vh;
}
`;

const TableDataGrey = styled.td`
font-size: 3vh;
color: LightGrey;
border: 1px solid LightGrey;
text-align: center;
vertical-align: middle;

@media only screen and (min-device-width : 320px) and (max-device-width : 480px)
 ,only screen and (min-device-width : 768px) and (max-device-width : 1024px){
    font-size 2vh;
}
`;

const SmallCol = styled.col`
width: 15%;
`
const LargeCol = styled.col`
width: 25%;
`
```

and here is the what and how it renders

```
{
    const { displayWidth } = this.props;
    const isMobile = displayWidth <= 480;

    if(isMobile) {
    return (            
        <Table id="leaderboard_view" >
        <TableHead onClick={this.handleCollapse}>LEADERBOARD</TableHead>
        <colgroup>
        <SmallCol/>
        <LargeCol/>
        <LargeCol/>
        <LargeCol/>
        </colgroup>
        { this.state.showLeaderboard ?  <tbody>
                    <tr>
                        <TableDataGrey>#</TableDataGrey>
                        <TableData>PLAYER</TableData>
                        <TableData>AWARD</TableData>
                        <TableData>SCORE</TableData>
                    </tr>
                    {list.map(user => 
                    <tr>
                    <TableDataGrey>{user.place}</TableDataGrey>
                    <TableData>{user.player}</TableData>
                    <TableData>{user.award}</TableData>
                    <TableData>{user.score}</TableData>
                    </tr>
                )}
                </tbody>  : null}
        </Table>

         )
        }
```

I thought if I just put the th before the col it would ignore it but it still only gets the SmallCol width which I think is weird since the `<TableDataGrey>` also gets the SmallCol. anyone had similar problem?

As you can see the th here is just as big as the first col but I need it to be 100% width of the whole table as I have said in the css.

[image]

Comment: It's still part of the Table. And it uses the first reference it can find. I had the same in standard html once.

Comment: is there someway to make it ignore the col since i still want the th to be a part of the table but just the td need the col

Comment: I'm not familiar with reactjs (yet). But from my experience it might help if you style your **th** more specifically. adding an **!important** if really necessary. There are numberous ways to make sure a th acts differently, but it all depends how you want it to look.

Comment: if you can provide js fiddle it will be easier to understand.

Comment: @Dramorian i have to rewrite it all to get it to work in jsfiddle but i provided a picture with the problem